# Configure Celery to talk to Redis via Unix socket

Tags: ubuntu, redis, celery

I would like Celery to build on Redis rather than the default RabbitMQ.

The [Celery documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/redis.html) explains:

> Configuration is easy, just configure the location of your Redis database:
>
> `BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'`
>
> Where the URL is in the format of:
>
> `redis://:password@hostname:port/db_number`
>
> all fields after the scheme are optional, and will default to localhost on port 6379, using database 0.

However, I have Redis set up NOT to listen to a port, but instead to listen to a socket.

Is there a URI scheme to support this?

Comment: just curious, whats the matter with redis not listening to a local port ?

Comment: Then the port is open to  the Internet...

Comment: thats not correct you can bind redis to 127.0.0.1 and make it accessible only to localhost or you can create firewall rules to restrict access only to a set of ip addresses.

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli: While that is correct, and they remain my fallback plans if I can't get a simple answer to this question, using a socket is ALSO [50% faster in throughput](http://redis.io/topics/benchmarks). If I don't need to use TCP, avoiding it is a security AND a performance win.

Comment: thats just a benchmark, celery is not going to make 100k queries per second to redis using a single worker machine (praise to you and your hardware if you can make it!) if you bind redis to TCP localhost you are not going to loose much.

Comment: Tommaso: It seems the answer is that it is impossible, and I am changing to use TCP. However, had the answer been, say, "Oh just use 'redis+socket://socket-path?db_number' for your URL", I would have preferred to use that, anyway. So the question still stands.

Comment: @Oddthinking I completely agree with you. Performance and Security been the key-word. If I have option to avoid a security risk of TCP access it is better than exposing myself to the risk and depending of the firewall to solve a risk that avoidable. Performance wise, there is NO REASON sacrificing for to TCP if there is no need for remote access

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Redis sockets are available since Celery 1.3. The syntax is:

```
BROKER_URL = 'redis+socket:///tmp/redis.sock'
```

If you want to use a specific database:

```
BROKER_URL = 'redis+socket:///tmp/redis.sock?virtual_host=1'
```

The documentation is not up-do-date, but you can check this issues for more details:

- https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1283
- https://github.com/celery/kombu/pull/238

Comment: What about the url for the celery result backend?

Answer (score 1):

The celery redis broker does not support socket connection, TCP connections is the only supported way at the moment.

I found this project, [celery-redis-unixsocket](https://github.com/piquadrat/celery-redis-unixsocket) on github after some googling. You might have a look if that works for you.